# How can I set up a VPN through which to access my work PC?

Tags: vpn, windows-firewall

I'm looking for some software that can work through a firewall, and that will allow me to set up a VPN that will allow me to access the same internal resources as my work PC can access.

Is there any free (or cheap) software that will let me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lots of options:

- teamviewer
- hamachi
- openvpn

and .. the most important option (just in case 'work' means 'company which i work for'):

- go and ask the admin of your company about what you are planning to do. i rather doubt that the company wants this without any notification.